# xCode 4.2 only show simulators of iPhone 5.0 and iPad 5.0

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

My Xcode 4.2 only shows show iPhone 5.0 Simulator and iPad 5.0 Simulator as seen in the picture. I already downloaded all versions os iOS in Preference/Download and have set up in the iOS Deployment Target to 3.0. Why doesn't it show all iOS simulators from 3.0 to 5.1 as in previous version of Xcode?

[image]

Comment: because you have not downloaded them. go to Preferences/Downloads and install necessary components.

Comment: I did this, but for some reason it does not show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for these simulators has been dropped. Currently the only simulators Xcode is supporting is for iOS 5+ SDKs.

Comment: so is it able to run on older version of iOS such as 3.1 3.2?

Comment: @DavidNg Your app may be able to run on devices running these iOS version depending on API support but you'll have to test this on real devices. From here on out you can NOT test 3.1 or 3.2 on the simulator.

Comment: I am able to test on physical iPhone iOS 4.1. Does it guarantee that it is able to run on iOS 4.1 or older versions when someone download from App store?

Comment: @DavidNg No there are too many variables to 100% guarantee it. But as long as you haven't used any methods that have been depreciated since 4.1 you should be alright.